# How to calculate a single accuracy for a model with multiple outputs in Keras?

Tags: keras, accuracy, multi-output

Consider the following, rather simple, model:

```py
x = Input(shape=(6,), name="input")

x = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name="dense_1")(x)
x = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', name="dense_2")(x)
x = layers.Dense(5120, activation='relu', name="dense_3")(x)

a_out = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='a_out')(x)
b_out = layers.Dense(20, activation='softmax', name='b_out')(x)
c_out = layers.Dense(30, activation='softmax', name='c_out')(x)

model = models.Model(input_layer, [a_out, b_out, c_out])

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
                loss={'a_out': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                      'b_out': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                      'c_out': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'},
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This model takes in a tensor of shape (6,) and outputs three different categorical values, `a_out`, `b_out`, and `c_out`. The metric that the model reports is accuracy but since there are 3 different outputs, it reports accuracy for each separately. Resulting in 3 different numbers.

Now, I want to wrap this model by `keras_tuner` and find the best combinations for layer sizes (as an example). But the problem is that `kt` makes its decision which combination is the best by looking at one single metric. The logical way of aggregating all three accuracies into one is to average them. But I don't see how I can do that!

If I try to introduce my own custom metric to Keras, like this:

```py
def overall_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy(y_true, y_pred)

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
                loss={'a_out': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                      'b_out': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                      'c_out': 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy'},
                metrics=[overall_accuracy])
```

I'm still bound by the same limitation as before since my `overall_accuracy` function is called once per each output and it does not get the chance to average the 3 accuracies. And if I introduce my own custom callback to be called at the end of each epoch, while I can calculate the average accuracy then, <del>it is not considered a metric and thus cannot be used by `kt`</del> (or at least that's what I know).

So, the question is, how to calculate one single accuracy when you model outputs multiple values?

Comment: Possibly similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680818/keras-custom-loss-as-a-function-of-multiple-outputs  You can add custom metrics via `model.add_metric()`

Comment: @Übermensch Thanks for the pointer but I'm not sure how to use the `add_metric` method. I mean in order to calculate my metric, I'll need the model's output and the target. I might have access to the model's output but where can I get the target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who might be facing the same question, here's a solution. Basically, it's answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61959143/join-metrics-of-every-output-in-keras-in-multiple-output). But I'm going to repeat the answer for the sake of completeness.

You can use a callback and combine the already calculated metrics into a new one. This means that the metric for each individual output should already be calculated using an entry in the `metrics` argument in the `compile` method`.

```py
class CombinedMetric(Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CombinedMetric, self).__init__()

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
        return

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        logs['accuracy'] = (logs["a_output_accuracy"] + logs["b_output_accuracy"] + logs["c_output_accuracy"]) / 3
        logs['val_accuracy'] = (logs["val_a_output_accuracy"] + logs["val_b_output_accuracy"] + logs["val_c_output_accuracy"]) / 3
```

The good news here is that the new metric is accessible to `keras-tuner` and can be used to tune your model.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe the default corss entropy categorical loss handles multiple outputs. I believe it works be when each output is the same though (for example, 10 boolean outputs). The advantage of the method you describe is it allows you to customize the outputs. The lets you do things such as weight the loss towards a certain variable.

Comment: @pseudoabdul Just to make sure there's no misunderstanding, I'm not interested in "total loss" for multiple outputs. I'm interested in "total accuracy" for multiple outputs. AFAIK, loss is always aggregated be default.